# Updating datasource2 through datasource1 in real-time

Tags: c#, datasource, windows-forms-designer

my question is simple and primitive!

I want to use the Windows Forms Application (visual c#) in Visual Studio 2013 to write a simple application to update datasource2 (shown in DataGridView2) by changing the value of the input data in datasource1 (shown in DataGridView1) in real-time. Can you show me how to do that!

The goal at the end is to write an application (client) to read the data in real-time (datasourec1) from some diveices (servers), and write the data on a databank (datasource2) for further processing.

thanks!

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question, y' know.

Comment: Thanks! I edited it to make the question clear!